# I've inserted an Account and Record Type in Test Class. I can retrieve the Record Type ID, but all other fields are blank (Name, Description)

Tags: record-type

The subsequent Contact and Activities have formula fields that load from the RT Name. But the RT Name is null so the other fields are also null.  The Record Type has Name, Descripton...etc.  But their not displaying.

```
Test.startTest();
//Get Account Record Type Id
Id accountRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Intermediary').getRecordTypeId();

List<Account> lstAccount= new List<Account>();

Account acc = new Account();
acc.Name = 'Test Account';
acc.Type = 'Investment Bank';
acc.RecordTypeId = accountRecordTypeId;
lstAccount.add(acc);

insert lstAccount;

System.debug ('Acct ID = ' + acc.id);
System.debug ('AcctName = ' + acc.Name);
System.debug ('acc Type = ' + acc.Type);

System.debug ('acc.RecordTypeId = ' + acc.RecordTypeId);
System.debug ('acc.RecordType Name = ' + acc.RecordType);
```

Comment: it sounds like [X-Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). For the formula to be correctly calculated, it is enough to populate `RecordTypeId` field on the account. Can you elaborate, what functionality working as not expected and what are you trying to check?

Answer (score 0):

You need to query them first.

```java
acc = [SELECT RecordType.Name, RecordType.Description FROM Account WHERE Id = :acc.Id];
System.debug(acc.RecordType.Name);
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried both: System.debug(acc.RecordType.Name);
System.debug(acc.RecordType.Description);  They return null.  acc.RecordTypeId returns the correct ID. I can access the fields via Workbench so I don't believe it's a permissions issue.

Comment: @Boots Updated my answer.